# Cannot Resolve symbol Environment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I Couldn't Resolve this Error **Environment** .

I couldnt Sort this , I have rebuilded , cleaned , Rebuilded Gradle . but couldnt solve this error

[image]

Comment: Try with `android.os.Environment`

Answer (score 7):

I guess you are missing below .

```
import android.os.Environment;
```

At first add this & then **`Clean-Rebuild Your Project`** .Hope this helps .